# Undefined AWS::S3 when define a method in helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I am following this tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-simple-music-streaming-app-with-ruby-on-rails/, but use the aws_sdk instead of aws_s3. I see basically they do the same thing. In the download part, I put the the download function into the model and it did show correctly the url to download, but from there I don't know how to trigger download so I moved the function to the helper and invoke it straight from view. From there rails keep complaining about **undefined method `model_name' for URI::HTTPS:Class**

This is the download method

```
def download song_key
  bucket = AWS::S3.new.buckets['mybucket'] # error from this line because undefined AWS::S3
  song = bucket.objects[song_key]
  song.url_for(:read, expires: 10*60)
end
```

This is the views

```
<% @songs.each do |song| %>
  <%= link_to "download", download(song.key) %>
<% end %>
```

Any idea how to fix it ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reading the stack trace slighty wrong - it's not your helper method raising the exception, but something inside `link_to`.

The `url_for` method is returning a `URI::HTTPS` instance. When the second argument to `link_to` is something other than a string, it assumes that it's an activemodel class and tries to find the appropriate route from that. For example if you do

```
link_to 'Show', person
```

and person is an instance of Person, link_to will end up generating the url from `person_path(person)`.

URIs aren't active model, so this process of finding the appropriate route fails. All you need to do is turn the URI into a string, for example

```
def download_url song_key
  bucket = AWS::S3.new.buckets['mybucket'] # error from this line because undefined AWS::S3
  song = bucket.objects[song_key]
  song.url_for(:read, expires: 10*60).to_s
end
```

Apparently the equivalent method in aws_s3 returning strings rather than URI objects which is qhy the tutorial you are following doesn't do this.